# Read Win32 Application Status through Java

Tags: java, windows, winapi

How to read win32 application status through java ? i need to read tool tips of application show on taskbar using java.

Comment: JNA is what most people use to communicate with c++ applications. You can download and read more about it from here https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson how could i read tool tips using this ?

Comment: please add more detail of what you exactly need . do you need application status ? or do you need Application tooltip from the taskbar ? those are 2 different things.

Comment: @CyprUS i need Application tooltip from the taskbar. when we point mouse to application icon on taskbar, we can see tooltip. i need to read it through java application.

Comment: @Bishan : do you need to read your own application's tooltip ? or some other application ? what type of application ?

Comment: @CyprUS i need to read Dropbox client application tooltip

Comment: @Bishan : please be clear , i assume that you want to read another app's tooltip from within your app. am i right?

Comment: @CyprUS : yes. you are correct. i want to read another app's tooltip from within my app.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a not-so simple approach , using Windows API. First , if you have the Window name of the Application, your approach becomes simpler. I will assume you do. Use `FindWindow` to get the Handle of the Application you are looking for . If the handle is successfully found , then you need to define a custom Windows message handler for message `TTM_NEEDTEXT` . For further help, please have a look at another stackoverflow question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333770/how-to-get-tooltip-text-for-a-given-hwnd)

Please note i have not yet attempted to do this on my own . Will try as soon as i can .