# How to Get Tooltip of a Window From Window Handle?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, tooltip, hwnd

I wrote a C++ win32 utility to read the title of open windows of a particular process. The intention is to check if that particular process is active, and if active determine which file is open in it. One way I can determine the open file is by reading the window title (it shows the file path as the title). However, if the path is too long, the title gets shortened. I noticed that it still shows the full path as a tool tip if I move the mouse over to the title area. So, I was wondering if there is anyway I can get the tool tip string from the Window handle.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333770/how-to-get-tooltip-text-for-a-given-hwnd/1334015#1334015) post asks the same question, but I couldn't arrive at a solution from the suggestions there.

Comment: I would imagine that it's only 'drawn' shortened and that calling `GetWindowText` on the app window would still give you the full title string.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am currently using GetWindowText() to get the title. It returns the shortened path.